# Is it correct to say that "we did not assume that a or b is positive." is equivalent to "we did not assume that a and b are both positive"?

Tags: language

Given a is a real number.

> We did not assume that a is positive.

For me, that sentence means either a is positive or a is not positive.

But given a and b are real numbers.

I read a sentence that "we did not assume that a or b is positive." in my textbook.

I wonder what meaning it has.

Are they

> we did not assume that a or b is positive.

> we did not assume that a and b are both positive

equivalent to each other?

> Is it correct to say that
>
> "we did not assume that a or b is positive."
>
> is equivalent to
>
> "we did not assume that a and b are both positive"?

I built a truth table that showed "tautology"

So can we say that?

Comment: p:='a is positive', q:='b is positive', so the 1st claim (we did not assume that a or b is positive) can be translated as ¬(p∨q) ⊢ ¬p∧¬q in classic propositional logic. It's not equivalent to 2nd claim (we did not assume that a and b are both positive) which should be translated as ¬(p∧q) ⊢ ¬p∨¬q...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running into the confusion that there are 2 definitions of "OR" in logic. The [common definition of OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) in logic allows for a, b and a&b to be true in order to have a true statement. Whereas the [colloquial use of OR is often called XOR (exclusive or)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) and only allows for one of the two to be true in order to have a true statement.

But either way these two statements are not the same, it could just be that they both fulfill the requirements for OR.